# Can substitute PyCharm Professional for CLion - primarily for python

Tags: python, c++, c, pycharm, clion

My favourite editor by far is PyCharm, mainly because I am most comfortable with Python.

I am subscribed to the professional package, but I am interested in picking up some C / C++.

CLion by default is paid, except for a 30 day trial. This is for personal use at the moment and picking up several suites could be too costly for me.

I have had a look around the net for information of the real differences between the Jetbrains ides, but cannot find anything concise (maybe I am just struggling to summarise my search with the correct keywords).

Anyway, how different are the various Jetbrains ides?
Is it just a matter of the same ide, different default settings and plugins?

Can i replace PyCharm with CLion altogether?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: CLion basically bundles PyCharm Community Edition as a plugin. Community features are mentioned here https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Thank you for responding, that matrix makes everything much clearer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a heavy user of CLion and PyCharm and have used InteliJ in the past. Each IDE feels like a fork of each other, and most keyboard bindings will work like jumping to a definition with cmd + b.

However, when it comes to tool chains, they are all heavily different. CLion relies on [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to understand your project and provide feedback that you would expect from any modern IDE.

With that said, it is not possible to add the tool chaining from CLion into PyCharm.

In my shop we use both Visual Studio Code and CLion. CLion feels decades ahead of VSC when it comes to "intelisense" in C. For example, having a code snippet of:

```c
int main(void)
{
  printf("CLion is the best!\n");
}
```

Naturally, you will get a red squiggle underneath `printf` because `<stdio.h>` is not included. If I click the suggestion to fix this error in VSC, I get "Would you like to disable squiggles" vs CLion you get "Would you like to include <stdio.h>". It is just a proper IDE with nice to have integration with GDB and Valgrind.

EDIT:

I am sorry, I just realized that you meant if you could replace PyCharm with CLion and not the other way around! Yes, you can absolutely use CLion to write some Python code. It uses all the features in the community edition.

Answer (score 1):

The different JetBrains IDEs are very similar and have the same look and basic features(Live Templates, code completion, etc.). You can even export your pycharm settings to CLion so that you retain your keymaps, color scheme, and other settings. There is a PyCharm Community Edition plugin which is available for CLion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will help me a lot in making my decision